# Nyquist-Shannon, aliasing and Fourier downsampling

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing, sampling

I want to know what is the proper way of downsampling a sampled signal using Fourier transform.

In [`scipy.signal.resample`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html) the [code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/802f4eac0eadd6c1372b0cf6c04d97ea26c00c57/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L2173-L2301) it first converts the signal to frequency domain, then discards the *middle half* of the frequencies (i.e. second and third quarters), then inverse-transform back to time domain. Therefore it is trying to keep the lowest and highest frequencies of the signal.

Due to Nyquist-Shannon we know that we cannot reconstruct a frequency of $f$ without at least $2f+1$ samples of the signal. Then when downsampling, shouldn't we discard the *second half* of the frequencies instead?

I already read related answers in [dsp.stackexchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) but couldn't find a good explanation, so I decided to try [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/52941/scipy-resample-fourier-method-explanation

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45446/pythons-tt-resample-vs-tt-resample-poly-vs-tt-decimate

Comment: If you want us to comment on a source file with $3521$ lines, it would make sense to provide the line number you're referring to.

Comment: @joriki sorry, I have edited to include link to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the first post you linked to:

> To downsample, it transforms to the frequency domain and deletes the second and third groups of $N/4$ elements (which correspond to the half with the highest frequency components).

So apparently you confused the middle half of the elements as stored in memory with the middle half of the frequencies.

Comment: I should have read more carefully